# Reactive Forms select won't obey FormControl after API data load

Tags: angular

I have a `select` field in a one-off form. I'm passing the `formField` into a component because the parent component is handling the data handshaking and passing the data into its subcomponents.

On initial load, the `select` is fine; it shows the associated record's accurate genre. However, when I make a selection and the API does its round trip, as soon as the field up updates, the selected `option` defaults to the first in the list ("generic"). This also means that I can never select "generic" because it's not registering as a change.

EDIT: If I avoid the *ngFor and hard-code the `option`s to the values of the passed-in `genreOptions`, everything works fine. Something about re-drawing the `option`s is causing the `value` to be set to default. Obviously, this is not optimal behavior. :)

The parent component:

```
this.genreField = new FormControl(this.genre);
this.genreOptions = [
  { value: 'generic', label: 'Generic' },
  { value: 'fantasy', label: 'Fantasy' },
  { value: 'sci-fi', label: 'Sci-Fi' },
];
saveGenre(value){do API stuff}
```

The parent template:

```
<app-form-select [formField]="genreField" [changeField]="saveGenre.bind(this)" label="Genre" [genreOptions]="genreOptions"></app-form-select>
```

The child component:

```
export class FormSelectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() genreOptions: { label: string, value: string }[];
  @Input() formField: FormControl;
  @Input() changeField: (value: string) => void;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.formField){
      console.log(this.formField.value,this.formField)
    }
  }
  onChange(event: Event){
    if(this.changeField)this.changeField(this.formField.value);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

The child's console output:

```
sci-fi FormControl {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, pristine: true, touched: false, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}asyncValidator: nullerrors: nullpristine: truestatus: "VALID"statusChanges: EventEmitter_ {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}touched: falsevalidator: nullvalue: "sci-fi"valueChanges: EventEmitter_ {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}_onChange: [ƒ]_onCollectionChange: () => { }_onDisabledChange: [ƒ]_pendingValue: "sci-fi"dirty: (...)disabled: (...)enabled: (...)invalid: (...)parent: (...)pending: (...)root: (...)untouched: (...)updateOn: (...)valid: (...)__proto__: AbstractControl
```

The child's template:

```
  <select [formControl]="formField" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let option of genreOptions" [selected]="option.value == formField.value" [value]="option.value">
      {{option.label}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

If I implement a `setTimeout` to set the value of the `FormControl` a second after changes are detected, it flicks it over and otherwise acts fine, but `setTimeout` to beat race conditions is folly.

As you can see, I've tried setting the selected attribute of the `option` but that attribute isn't reflected in the DOM. I've also tried setting the `value` of the `select` itself, no dice.

I am using this pattern for `input`s, `textarea`s, and `checkbox`es all over my app, so the data flow doesn't seem to be the issue. In fact, when I stick a dummy `input` element into the same component as a sibling of the `select`, the `input` changes as it's supposed to, and the select bounces back to "Generic" as soon as it gets new data.

TLDR: `select` has correct selected value on page load, but changes to default on component changes

fwiw, the input is being updated somewhere in `core.js:7222` after changes are detected:

```
    if (components !== null) {
        refreshChildComponents(lView, components);
    }
```

and the select is being blanked out somewhere in `browser.js:3037` after changes are detected:

```
        try {
            players = this._flushAnimations(cleanupFns, microtaskId);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `this.formField.value` here, use the value from the `event: Event` parameter,  `this.formField.value` is still holding the initial value here.

```
  onChange(event: Event){
    if(this.changeField)this.changeField(this.formField.value);
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
```

You're basically setting the `FormControl` twice - in your template where you bind the `formField` and in `changeField` callback.

Side tip - you can use `@Output` and `EventEmitter` instead of passing `changeField` callback as an `@Input`

Comment: Don't understand that you're saying. `this.formField.value` is NOT holding the initial value. It's being changed appropriately AND is reporting the new value in the `this.changeField()` callback. The API is returning the freshly changed value, and when the component is redrawn, the `FormControl` is defaulting to the first select option for some unknown reason. As I said, everything works fine when I hard-code the options. I'm not sure why you think that the initial value is being held, when all that displays is "Generic" after flashing the correct value when I bump btw "Fantasy" and "Sci-Fi"..

Comment: "You're basically setting the FormControl twice - in your template where you bind the formField and in changeField callback." HOW is the `this.changeField()` setting the value? I'm reading the value, not using `.setValue()` And I'm never setting the value to "Generic" in my tests. that's being done several hundred function calls after new data during some kind of garbage collection. The value is fine until then.

Comment: did you try in using event.currentTarget.value instead of this.formField.value in onChange method?